# Firestore promise chaining 2nd chain onsnapshot cant find document

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, es6-promise, chaining

react,redux,es6, firestore onsnapshot querying

I want to update a set of questions based on when a blog changes which itself changes when a category changes.

I've managed to set the blog with firestore querying.

However when I try to chain onSnapshot with promises, the 2nd onSnapshot fails.
I'm calling the 2nd onsnapshot together with update as the 2nd chain with promise all.

What isn't clear to me is why Firestore doesn't find the document in the 2nd onSnapshot.

Increment method is based on the firebase increment method:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment()
```

Every help is welcome, thanks in advance

My code:

all inside a redux toolkit thunk action:

```
export const getMainBlog = category => dispatch => {
...
}
```

setting paths for firestore to be used later:

```
const blogInCategoryCounter = firebase.db.collection(`categories/${category}/local-blogs`);
const getBlog = blogInCategoryCounter.orderBy("counterShownAllUsers","desc").limit(1)
const blogQuestionIndex = 
firebase.db.collection("categories").doc(category).collection("blog-question-index");
```

first promise returned from function in the chain:

```
const getDoc = () => {          
          let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {           
              getBlog.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                const data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {                
                 if (doc.exists){                 
                 return ({
                   id: doc.id,
                   ...doc.data()
                 })                              
                 }else{   
                  console.log("blog not found");                
                   return null;
                 }          
               })
               const [dataExtracted] = data
               resolve(dataExtracted)
              })                             
            })
              return promise;
            }
```

2nd chain of promises including an update method and another onSnapshot:

```
    const updateCounterBlog = data => {
                  let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                    const returnedFromUpdate = blogInCategoryCounter.doc(data.id).update({
                      counterShownAllUsers: firebase.increment(1)
                    })
                    returnedFromUpdate.then(() => resolve(data))
                  })
                  return promise  
                }
                
                const extractQuestionIndexQuestions = data => {
                  let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {                                 
                      blogQuestionIndex.doc(data.id).onSnapshot(doc => {                                                                            
                          if (doc.exists){                                                                                                                       
                             resolve(doc.data())                                                                  
                          }else{
                             reject("index doc not found")                   
                          }
                        })                                                     
                  })
                  return promise;
                }
```

array of promises:

```
        const promiseArray = [extractQuestionIndexQuestions,updateCounterBlog]
```

invocation:

```
getDoc().then(data => {
            Promise.all(promiseArray.map(callback => callback(data))).then(values => {              
               const blog = {
                      blogData: data,
                      blogId: data.id,
                      category: category,
                      blogQuestionIndex: values[0]
                    }                                                
              dispatch(loadBlog(blog)) // for redux thunk
            })                         
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive got it to work,
Now Im pretty sure it was a space typo in the data entry on the server.

sorry for the trouble if anyone took a look and tried to help,
thanks if you did!

Comment: Thank you for self-answering, please consider marking your answer as correct!!